# linq to xml skipwhile() takewhile()

Tags: c#, linq

I have this xml

```
<root>
<TR_ZAL IDZ="cOY9" O="0">
</TR_ZAL>
<TR_ZAL IDZ="FOXd" O="10">
</TR_ZAL>
<TR_ZAL IDZ="wAW5" O="1">
<TR_ZAL IDZ="AWak" O="1">
</TR_ZAL>
<TR_ZAL IDZ="XpPp" O="10">
</TR_ZAL>
<TR_ZAL IDZ="asTu" O="10">
</TR_ZAL>
<TR_ZAL IDZ="y9VV" O="1">
</TR_ZAL>
</root>
```

and I know the `IDZ` `"AWak"` and my task is to get the element with known `IDZ` and all after it until the next element with same attribute `O` and if there isn't any other then I should get all remaining elements. In this case it should be

```
<TR_ZAL IDZ="AWak" O="1">
</TR_ZAL>
<TR_ZAL IDZ="XpPp" O="10">
</TR_ZAL>
<TR_ZAL IDZ="asTu" O="10">
</TR_ZAL>
```

so i tried to use  linq, but I can't find my mistake, so can anyone please halp me?

```
IEnumerable<XElement> rozsah = xmlText.Root.Elements("TR_ZAL")
                  .SkipWhile(x => x.Attribute("IDZ").Value != "AWak")
                  .Take(1)
                  .TakeWhile(x =>Convert.ToInt32(x.Attribute("O").Value) != o);
```

Comment: Your input XML is not valid (not all TR_ZAL has closed tag). Could you fix it? Do you have hierarchy here or everything is just a list of TR_ZAL?

Comment: Oh I am sorry the xml is invalid only due to copy paste mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your XML should be valid with this change:

```
<root>
<TR_ZAL IDZ="cOY9" O="0">
</TR_ZAL>
<TR_ZAL IDZ="FOXd" O="10">
</TR_ZAL>
<TR_ZAL IDZ="wAW5" O="1">
</TR_ZAL>
<TR_ZAL IDZ="AWak" O="1">
</TR_ZAL>
<TR_ZAL IDZ="XpPp" O="10">
</TR_ZAL>
<TR_ZAL IDZ="asTu" O="10">
</TR_ZAL>
<TR_ZAL IDZ="y9VV" O="1">
</TR_ZAL>
</root>
```

If this is true, then answer on your question below:

```
int? o = null;
IEnumerable<XElement> rozsah = xmlText.Root
    // Getting all child 'TR_ZAL' from root object
    .Elements("TR_ZAL")
    // Ignoring until we will not meet TR_ZAL with IDZ == AWak
    .SkipWhile(x => x.Attribute("IDZ").Value != "AWak")
    // Cache the first value of elements in collection and compare each next item
    // we want to take only items which does not have the same value
    .TakeWhile(x =>
        {
            int oAttributeValue = XmlConvert.ToInt32(x.Attribute("O").Value);

            if (!o.HasValue)
            {
                o = oAttributeValue;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return o != oAttributeValue;
            }
        });
```

You linq has a bug that when you find first IDZ = AWak - next your step is to take 1 element `Take(1)` and so after this `Take(1)` will return you collection with just one element, so next your step `TakeWhile(...)` operates on the collection with this one element, not with the rest of elements after.

Comment: Thank you I thought that the `take(1)` just takes one element and moves the cursor, but now I get it